# Remove git coloring from Intellij

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij Idea for a github repo I recently closed down, but It's still showing red names for classes I haven't pushed to the repo yet. Is there away I can tell the IDE not to monitor my file commits without remaking the project and copying file manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either deactivate the git integration completely or -if the coloring is the annoying part for you- change the colors.

Deactivate: Go to Preferences -> Plugins and uncheck Git Integration (Note: this will also disable the GitHub plugin)

Change colors: Preferences -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> File Status

After saving your current theme as a copy you can modify the colors to your liking.